# A question on sequential space and Frechet-Urysohn space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a [sequential space (or Frechet-Urysohn space)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269032/understanding-two-similar-definitions-frechet-urysohn-space-and-sequential-spac). Must the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x):x\in X\} \subset X \times X$ as a subspace be a sequential space  (or Frechet-Urysohn space)?

Comment: The diagonal $\Delta$ is homeomorphic to $X$...

Comment: Dear @HennoBrandsma : Please consider turning your comment into a hint. If you are worried it sounds too "light" then put "hint: " in front of it and you'll be fine. It's a good hint! And in the future, please try to do the same, so that we can unclutter the unanswered questions list. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint: the diagonal $\Delta$ is homeomorphic to $X$.