# Is the Alexandrov extension the unique $k_2$-Hausdorff one-point compactification of a KC space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Definitions:

- [KC (P100)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000100): each compact subset of the space is closed.
- [$k_2$-Hausdorff (P171)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000171): for every compact $T_2$ space and continuous map $f:K\to X$ and points $k,l\in K$ with $f(k)\not=f(l)$, there exist open neighborhoods $U,V$ of $k,l$ with $f[U],f[V]$ disjoint.
- [Alexandrov extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension): the space $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$ such that neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the complements of compact-and-closed subsets of $X$.
- Compactification: a space $Y\supseteq X$ such that $Y$ is compact and $X$ is dense.

It's [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427052/showing-one-point-compactification-is-unique-up-to-homeomorphism) that the Alexandrov extension is the unique Hausdorff one-point compactification of a space whenever the Alexandrov extension is Hausdorff. It's also [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4761212/86887) that the Alexandrov extension of any $KC$ space is $k_2$-Hausdorff.

Is the Alexandrov extension the unique $k_2$-Hausdorff one-point compactification of a KC space?

Comment: Also, from the proof in the linked answer, you could replace "Hausdorff" with $KC$, ie, the proof there shows that if the Alexandrov extension of a space is $KC$, then it is the unique $KC$ one-point compactification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case, even if the original uncompactified space is locally compact Hausdorff.  For a counterexample, consider $X=\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean topology, and let $Y=X\cup \{\infty\}$ with the neighborhoods of $\infty$ consisting of sets $U\cup\{\infty\}$ where $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ is dense, open, and cocompact.

A very similar space ($[0,1]\cup\{\infty\}$) is constructed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4778063/1210477) and is shown there to be $k_2$-Hausdorff.  The exact same argument shows our space $Y$ is $k_2$-Hausdorff as well.

Moreover, $Y$ is certainly compact, since any open cover of $Y$ includes a neighborhood of the form $U\cup\{\infty\}$, with $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ cocompact. And $X$ is dense in $Y$, since $\infty$ is not isolated.

Thus even $\mathbb R$ has another $k_2$-Hausdorff one-point compactification.

##### Remark.

$Y$ is not $KC$, as compact intervals in $\mathbb R$ are not closed in $Y$.  This is to be expected, since as observed in the comments, the arguments in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/427131/1210477) show that a space can have at most one $KC$ one-point compactification (everything in the linked answer is stated for Hausdorff spaces, but only $KC$ is used.)