# What separation properties are guaranteed in sequentially discrete spaces?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

A [sequentially discrete (P167)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000167) space has the property that all converging sequences are eventually constant. As a result, all such spaces are [US (P99)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000099), that is, they have Unique Sequential limits. Therefore all such spaces are $T_1$.

On the other hand, such spaces need not be Hausdorff. Consider for example [Cocountable topology on the real numbers (S17)](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000017) - this space is [hyperconnected (P39)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000039) (a.k.a. "anti-Hausdorff") as all non-empty open sets intersect, but since all countable subsets of the space are closed, we have that the space is sequentially discrete.

Might sequentially discrete spaces guarantee a separation property strictly stronger than US, but weaker than Hausdorff? See e.g. [How are k-Hausdorff and weakly Hausdorff distinct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760309/how-are-k-hausdorff-and-weakly-hausdorff-distinct/4761212#4761212) or follow the trailhead at https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000425 for possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828939/1210477) we know a space can be sequentially discrete but fail to be [$k_2$-Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000171):  Let $\beta\omega$ be the [Stone-Čech compactification of the naturals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000108), and let $X=\beta\omega\cup \{p'\}$, where $p'$ is a duplicate of some non-isolated point $p\in \beta\omega$, i.e., the neighborhoods of $p'$ are those of the form $\{p'\}\cup U\backslash \{p\}$ for some neighborhood $U\subseteq \beta\omega$ of $p$.

Then $X$ is sequentially discrete, yet not $k_2H$, since the map $f\colon \beta\omega\to X\times X$ given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
(x, x) & x\neq p\\
(p,p') & x= p
\end{cases}
$$ witnesses that the diagonal is not $k_2$-closed.

While I believe $k_2H$ is the only property in $\pi$-base that is an immediate strengthening of $US$ with no other properties between it, we could also ask if sequentially discrete might imply $P$ for some other strengthening $P$ of $T_1$ that lies between $T_1$ and $T_2$.  Then we would arguably have $US+P$ as a better strenthenening than just $US$.

However, the only other such strengthenings that are immediate strengthenings of $T_1$ (i.e., no other properties sandwiched between them) that I saw on $\pi$-base were $RC$ ([retracts are closed](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000101)), [semi-Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000169), and [locally Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000195).

This same example shows neither of the first two of these need be true: to see that $RC$ fails we observe that
$$r(x)=\begin{cases}
x & x\neq p'\\
p & x= p'
\end{cases}
$$
is a retraction, so that $\beta\omega\subset X$ is a non-closed retract.

Semi-Hausdorff fails, since $p$ and $p'$ cannot be separated by a regular open neighborhood of $p$.

$X$ does happen to be locally Hausdorff, but the [cocountable topology on an uncountable set](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000017) is sequentially discrete and not locally Hausdorff.

(Actually, on reflection it's easy to see that the cocountable topology fails to be semi-Hausdorff or $RC$ as well, but I will leave the other example as it stands, since the cocountable topology is $k_2$-Hausdorff, and much more.)

##### Remark.

On a more positive note, we do have (as remarked in the same answer linked above), that a sequentially discrete space will be "$SUS$" ("strongly" $US$ in that question), meaning *continuous* transfinite sequences have unique limits, as defined in more detail in the linked question.