# A question about the closure of countable discrete subset

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be Hausdorff. Given any countable discrete $D \subset X$, is the closure $cl(D)$ as a subspace of $X$ [Frechet-Urysohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269032/understanding-two-similar-definitions-frechet-urysohn-space-and-sequential-spac)?

**Added:** If I may ask more, is it must be discretely generated?

> A space is called discretely generated if for every $A\subset X$ with $x \in cl(A)$ there is a discrete $D\subset A$ such that $x \in cl(D)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Consider the Stone–Čech compactification $\beta \omega$ of $\omega$.  We know that $\omega$ countable and discrete.  However $\overline{ \omega }$ is not Fréchet, since $\omega$ is a dense subset of $\beta \omega$, and we know that $\beta \omega$ is not Fréchet (as pointed out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/281725/8348)).