# Topology problems on closure of a set and limit points

Tags: general-topology

[image]

[image]

[image]

Need help here guys, In problem 2.26, I dont have an example which satisfies both the criteria. Each and every time, I am getting either of them but not both of them.

In example 2.30, I am not sure but I think open sets are going to be the set of natural numbers (symbolized as N) and closed sets will be {0} and empty set. But I dont know the limit points and other parameters.

In 2.32, I am completely clueless as to what its asking , because if x is a limit point of Y, then it implies that it can be a sequential limit point of Y. But here, its asking me the opposite.

I did this for 2.30, but my instructor told me to explain the points (ii) and (iii) while verifying that Ts is a topology. He told me that you will have to show the other ones too since its just not those elements but also its a finite sub-collection of elements of T for union and intersection. I don't know how many to show, since its an entire set of Natural nos.

[image: Problem 2.30 which I solved]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $b$ be a bijection from $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb Q$ and consider the topology $\mathcal T$ on $\mathbb N$ defined by$$\mathcal T=\{S\subset\mathbb N\mid b(S)\text{ is open with respect to the usual topology on }\mathbb Q\}.$$Now, take $A=b^{-1}\bigl((-1,1)\bigr)$. Then $\overline A=b^{-1}\bigl([-1,1]\bigr)$.

The other problem has already been answered [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409317/when-is-an-accumulation-point-not-the-limit-of-some-sequence-in-a-topological-sp).

Answer (score 1):

2.26 Take the topology $\mathcal{T} = \{\Bbb N \setminus F: F \subseteq \Bbb N \text{ finite }, 0 \notin F\} \cup \{A \subseteq \Bbb N: 0 \notin A\}$. Then $A=\{2n+1: n \in \Bbb N\}$ is not closed, and it closure is $A \cup \{0\} \neq \Bbb N$.

2.30 The problem described you what the open sets are. The closed sets are their complements: i.e. all sets of the form $\{1,2,\ldots, N-1\}$ plus $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb N$ of course. If a set $A$ is infinite, all points of $\Bbb N$ are limit points of it. Think for yourself what limit points of finite sets can be, using the definition. As the space is first countable, all limit points will be sequential limit points as well.

2.32 Take $\Bbb R$ in the [cocountable topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) and $A = [0,1]$. Then $\pi$ is a limit point of $A$, but not a sequential limit point.

Comment: I am confused with 2.26, what is F? Is it a 2nd set which has no connection with set A? Also, Instead of F if I say that's set A too will it be a problem??

Comment: I saw your 2.30 solution, that's a nice explanation. I used definitions of limit points and sequential limit points to answer the last 2 questions.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun $F$ runs over the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$, as I say; I use $F$ for finite, $A$ is also fine, it's only a name. That first part of the topology are the neighbourhoods of $0$, all other points are isolated.

Answer (score 0):

For problem 2.26, just go minimalist: You need a closed set that is neither empty nor the full space, thus you need an open set with that property (because closed sets are the complements of open sets). Therefore just define *one* such open set, say $\{0\}$. That is, the topology is $\mathcal T=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\mathbb N\}$. Then you just need to select a non-empty proper subset of that one non-trivial closed set, say $A=\{1\}$. Then $\overline A = \mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$ which clearly is neither $A$ nor $\mathbb N$.

Comment: how are sure that the topology which you defined exist and will work? There are 3 conditions for checking whether (T) which you defined is a topology. 1st and 2nd conditions (i.e. empty set and N belong to T works and also finite sub-collection of T, i.e. their intersection is going to work. But, will the other condition (i.e. union of the sub collections of T work)?? I have a doubt there.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun: There are only eight subcollections. Moreover, the empty set obviously doesn't change the union, so you only have to check the four collections that don't contain the empty set. Anything that contains the full space will have the full space as union, so they always work, so what remains to check are the two subcollections that don't contain the full space either. One of them is the empty collection, which also works in any topology, giving the empty set. The remaining collection contains just one set, and single-set collections obviously work, too.