# Retract subspace of metric space is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\varrho)$ be a metric space, and $Y\subseteq{X}$ a retract subspace of $X$. Show that $Y$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $A$ that converges to a point $x\in X$. Since $A$ is a retract subspace, there is a continuous map $r:X\to A$ such that $r(a)=a$ for every $a\in A$. By continuity, we have $a_n=r(a_n)\to r(x)$. By uniqueness of limits in a metric space, we have $x=r(x)\in A$. Therefore $A$ is closed.

By replacing sequences by nets, this can be generalized to any Hausdorff space $X$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, my textbook claims that a sequence converging to a point in the subspace does not necessarily imply that the subspace is closed. Is there something about the fact that it is retract that allows this?

Comment: @mrose No it's a general topological property. A set $A$ is closed in a metric space (or more generally, a first countable space) iff whenever a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ converges to a point $x\in X$, then $x\in A$. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760594/limit-of-a-sequence-and-a-closed-set

Comment: I'm sorry, topology confuses me quite a bit. The textbook says it is not true "for a general topological space." Is this wrong?

Comment: It's correct. A metric space is not a general topological space. For a general topological space you need a different notion of convergence, like nets. But for metric spaces, sequences suffice.

Comment: It's starting to make sense. Thank you